# Il n'y avait pas de jour où... ne... + verb tense/mood

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical

I'd like to double-check my understanding of this construction in French. It seems that if you're being formal, you use l'imparfait du subjonctif, and otherwise, you use l'imparfait de l'indicatif (but still with a single ne). From some examples found on google:

> La fatigue faisait paraître encore plus pénible le manque de vivres, car il n'y avait pas de jour où l'on ne fût obligé de porter les canots et leur chargement à une distance plus ou moins longue...
>
> ---
>
> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le Prophète ne venait nous rendre visite matin et soir.

Even with l'indicatif, is this still a fairly formal turn of phrase? Would you ever use this kind of thing in spoken French?

Answer (score 2):

*Would you ever use this kind of thing in spoken French?*

Not that much. The sentences you selected are quite far from average day-to-day spoken French.
If we keep the first part of these sentences unchanged, we feel compelled to stick to a literary style for consistency.

But first, here are some attempts at everyday spoken French, losing the point of your question in the process:

> La fatigue rendait encore plus pénible le manque de nourriture parce que tous les jours, on devait porter les canots et leur chargement […]
>
> ---
>
> Tous les matins et tous les soirs, le Prophète venait chez nous.

If we stay close to the original phrasing, I believe the imperfect indicative is the usual tense:

> Il n'y avait pas de jour où il ne fallait pas qu'on porte les canots, (or "pas de jour où on n'avait pas à porter les canots.")
>
> ---
>
> Il n'y avait pas un jour où il ne venait pas chez nous.

The main clause could also be in the present tense instead of the imperfect:

> Il n'y a pas un jour où on a pas eu à porter les canots

Answer (score 1):

La préférence donnée au subjonctif dans ton exemple n'est pas une question de paraître plus ou moins formel.

Dans ton exemple l'usage du subjonctif (imparfait) peut sembler (à certains) un peu vieilli mais, traditionnellement, c'est l'usage pour, entre autres, marquer une nuance d'obligation, ce qui est explicitement le cas.

*il n'y avait pas de jour où l'on n'**était** obligé*, la phrase reste très correcte et ne fera aucun doute à l'écrit. Mais... à l'oral... je préférerai pour ma part l'imparfait du subjonctif en raison de la négation *on **n**'était* qui pourrait être confondue avec une liaison *on-était* et, disparaissant, donner, à l'oreille, une phrase assez bancale.

EDIT : On notera que, dans le contexte d'obligation, l'usage du subjonctif est resté très vivant pour exprimer poliment un impératif.

Answer (score 1):

Si le verbe de la principale est à un temps du passé le verbe de la subordonnée se met traditionnellement à l'imparfait du subjonctif. Cependant, dans la langue parlée, il reste convenable d'utiliser le passé  du subjonctif et même le présent du subjonctif; c'est en réalité ce que la majorité des personnes éduquées utilisent actuellement dans la langue parlée et même dans la langue écrite.

> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le Prophète ne vienne nous rendre visite matin et soir.
>
> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le Prophète ne soit venu nous rendre visite matin et soir.

Cela reste vrai lorsque l'action du verbe de la subordonnée est antérieure à celle du verbe de la principale, alors que traditionnellement on escompte le plus que parfait.

> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le prophète avant de nous rendre visite n'eût préparé une gentille et très courte allocution à notre égard. (*traditionnel et préférable dans la langue écrite*)

Mais, dans la langue parlée les possibilités suivantes (présent ou passé) sont très acceptables.

> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le prophète avant de nous rendre visite n'ait préparé une gentille et très courte allocution à notre égard. (**très acceptable**, opinion personnelle)
>
> Il n'y avait pas de jour où le prophète avant de nous rendre visite ne prépare une gentille et très courte allocution à notre égard. (**pas aussi acceptable que le précédent**, opinion personnelle)

Comment: Si on s'interdit l'imparfait du subjonctif (ce qui est la norme actuelle à l'oral), rien d'autre que l'imparfait de l'indicatif ne me parait acceptable dans ces phrases. Il peut y avoir d'autres possibilités, mais seulement si on change la première partie de la phrase en « Il n'y a pas eu de jour ».

Comment: @ Stéphane Gimenez♦ Vous pensez que présent et passé du subjonctif ne sont pas utilisés; cela me *parait* contraire à mon expérience du français parlé et c'est contraire à ce que l'on peut lire dans les rapports de la banque de dépannage du Québec ( http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1175) : - La direction avait souhaité que le personnel fût (ou soit) informé régulièrement. (fût, imparfait du subjonctif, ou soit, présent du subjonctif). Il pourrait être question de ce « *passé*» de l'indicatif; il inclu cependant imparfait et plus que parfait sans équivoque.

Comment: Note qu'« avait souhaité » est un temps composé. Ce n'est donc pas similaire à ce que l'on trouve dans cette question. Et il faut aussi savoir que dans l'exemple de l'OQLF, même si présent et imparfait du subjonctif sont tous deux possibles, les phrases qui en résultent n'ont pas exactement le même sens.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est un temps composé du passé de l'indicatif, donc un  temps du passé de l'indicatif; c'est ce que stipule l'OQLF : temps du passé de l'indicatif; le rapport  va  plus loin et il est ajouté « ou du conditionnel ». De plus il n'est pas question de sens dans ce rapport; est-ce que vous pensez devoir invalider ce qu'il asserte? J'emploie moi-même ces concordances de temps! Je ne les ai certainement pas inventées…Je ne prétend pas cependant que du fait que je les utilisent elles soient nécessairement idéales ou souhaitables ou qu'elles ne soient pas passibles d'être changées.